# enabled download button if file is available with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, ajax

I'm trying to implement some logic for my UI.

1. First the download button is in disabled state after an image uploaded.
2. Once the Image is processed and it will generate an text file in a particular directory which will updated in database.
3. Once the converted file available the download button automatically need to be enabled.

The refresh should need to be done only for the button not the whole page.

I have already tried setTimeout but the issue is entire page getting refreshed.

Edited with code. So far i have updated this below code for page refresh for every 5 seconds. But the problem is my entire page getting reloaded.

```
setTimeout(function(){
location.reload();
},5000);
```

Thanks in advance.

My project is under development with Django framework.

Comment: please show your efforts first(post Your code)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: You can use AJAX Upload, when uploaded and have response from server, enable download button.

Comment: use ajax call to do this and send any flag for result like true or false based on that remove disable of your dowload button, you don't need to refresh anything,not even your button.

Comment: @kaushalshah I'have edited my post. Also i'm not asking the code. I have done my effort very well. I'm trying to get some idea about how to implement. Don't advice if you are not willing to provide some ideas.

Comment: @Divyarajsinh thanks mate let me try as per your suggestion.

Comment: @Swaminathan Thanks for your advice. its really help me in future

Comment: @kaushalshah No problem mate. :)

Comment: Then the question is too broad and therefore off topic for SO (as well as off topic for being primarily opinion based if you are only after advice).  Please see what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for that:

```
$.get( "check_button.php", function( data ) {
  if( data == 'true' )
    $( "#download_button" ).prop( 'disabled', false );
});
```

This involes a second file which gets refreshed in the background and does the check.

Comment: Okay thank you i will check the jquery documentation then. Thanks for the advice.